# installing mysql client on docker php

Tags: mysql, docker

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
```

I do `docker exec -it <hash> bash` from the CLI and then do `mysql` and get a `bash: mysql: command not found` error.

I do `apt-get install mysql` and the package can't be located. I get the same error when I try to install `mysql-client` and `mysql-server`.

If I want to install mysql in Ubuntu `mysql-client` does the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to customize your Dockerfile to install the mysql client on your image.

You should have to add something like after the FROM :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client && rm -rf /var/lib/apt
```

and of course rebuild your image.

Comment: For the purpose of doing it via bash I had to do `apt-get update`. I had erroneously assumed that the apt file was already up-to-date since it's a fresh Docker container. Like on Linux maybe the apt file isn't as up to date as it could be but it's decently enough up-to-date to work outside of the box.. –

Comment: @Vincent This approach doesn't seem to find mysql-client on `FROM php:8.1.5-fpm` either. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

my docker image: `debian:stable-20200720-slim`

`mysql-clinet` didn't work for me. after adding `contrib` and `non-free` to source.list execute this command:

```
apt-get update && apt install mariadb-client
```

then client works just fine.

Comment: I didn't have to add anything to the `source.list`, but this worked!